# ckeditor: how to encapsulate rendering?

Tags: symfony, ckeditor, easyadmin

Please excuse my English (google translate).
I am using FOSCKEditorBundle with easyadmin 4.
For my rendering to be really identical to that of my site, the value of the textarea must be surrounded by two divs, like this:

```
<section id="sectInterne">
   <article class="artInterne">
       {{ value }}
   </article>
</section>
```

To test, I modified the ckeditor_widget.html.twig file and it works fine as I want.
Of course this is not the right method, since the added code is saved in db when I save and in addition my modification would be overwritten during updates.
So how could I encapsulate the content of my textarea in html code ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I understood your problem correctly but :

If you want to display the html from your database you can use

```
{{ value|raw }}
```

If you want to store the text in your database you can use a dedicated CkeditorType in your formtype.

````php
use FOS\CKEditorBundle\Form\Type\CKEditorType;

$builder->add('field', CKEditorType::class, array(
    'config' => array(
        'uiColor' => '#ffffff',
        //...
    ),
));```
````

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for your answer, but that's not what I'm trying to do. I wanted to add html tags around the textarea without these tags being saved in bdd.
I worked around the problem by removing the tags added on the php side before saving and it works.
I still have to succeed in overriding the twig file so that my modification does not get deleted during updates. This will be the subject of another question, because it is no longer the same problem.
Thanks again.